Impdp DIRECT_PATH way slower than other methods
I am currently testing how to make hot clones of an Oracle schema from a server to another.
I want something that can be done programmatically, without specific access to the database storage or OS.
This seems to work:
impdp usr/pwd@oradb/PDB network_link=sourcedblink schemas=XXX exclude=statistics ACCESS_METHOD=XXX

If I let ACCESS_METHOD by default (= DIRECT_PATH), the process is slow as hell, and very small tables take multiple seconds to import (ex 3 rows and 6 integer columns = 4s).
However, with INSERT_AS_SELECT the performance is acceptable (4x faster), and time spent is linear compared to table content.
Do you know what conditions can slow down DIRECT_PATH access method?
My test environment: 2 Oracle XE databases (21 or 23, one on windows and the other on WSL).
Oracle XE doesn't support parallel imports/exports.
